# Rails 5 Active Storage: display multiple images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I am building a small CMS on Rails 5 to manage my online portfolio as picture book illustrator.

I am using Active Storage to upload and display images, but while the upload part works fine I still have some troubles with displaying them.

In my database I have a table called `Works` (which obviously represents the books that I work on), and each book has one single cover illustration and various illustrations.

In my `Work` model I defined the relationship [as the Active Storage documentation suggests](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-many-attached):

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord
   :has_many_attached :illustrations
end
```

In my controller I am using the [with_attached_illustrations](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1056) method in this way:

```
def show
    @project = Work.with_attached_illustrations.find(params[:id])
end
```

While in my view I am doing:

```
<% if @project.illustrations.attached? %>
                <%= @project.illustrations.each do |illustration| %>
                        <%= image_tag(illustration, :class => "illustrations") %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
```

And this is the browser this is the output:

```
<img class="illustrations" src="http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--6766bc0bb57edf83ed29796e499d453019f10f3d/%C2%A901.jpg">
[#<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 6, name: "illustrations", record_type: "Work", record_id: 9, blob_id: 6, created_at: "2019-07-17 01:55:04">]
```

Images are getting displayed fine, but I get that line with `[#ActiveStorage::Attachment ...` for every image that gets loaded.

What should I do in order to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this in your code:

```
<%= @project.illustrations.each do |illustration| %>
```

Get rid of the = sign in front of it, so it reads:

```
<% @project.illustrations.each do |illustration| %>
```

Comment: ...can't believe I didn't notice it! Now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you have '=' equal sign in the first line. Remove it and your loop would be like this.

```
<% @project.illustrations.each do |illustration| %>
    <%= image_tag url_for(illustration), :class => "illustrations" %>
<% end %>
```